# How to align a div to be exactly under the middle of another div

Tags: html, css, alignment, inline, text-align

I have to lists of data, one with id of `dates` and other one with id of `nums`.
The number of letters in date and num is not equal so how Can I put each of divs in nums be exactly under dates?

```css
#dates div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#nums div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="dates">
        <div>Aug 5</div>
        <div>Aug 6</div>
        <div>Aug 7</div>
        <div>September 12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nums">
        <div>9</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

For example, in here `3` should go to right because it should be **exactly down of the middle** of september.
I don't need pixel things like margin and left and right. because the nums may change but it must still be in the down of middle of it's date.
Thanks

Comment: Seriously use a `table` it will be much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a `table` (and you should), use CSS Tables.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#nums,
#dates {
  display: table-row;
}

.showwidth {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="dates">
  <div class="showwidth">Aug 5</div>
  <div class="showwidth">Aug 6</div>
  <div class="showwidth">Aug 7</div>
  <div class="showwidth">September 12</div>
</div>
<div id="nums">
  <div class="showwidth">9</div>
  <div class="showwidth">7</div>
  <div class="showwidth">5</div>
  <div class="showwidth">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MehanAlavi I only see divs here and not tables ... did you check the code?

Comment: hmm, I think It's really useful if a can delete the border. Thanks let me see does it work

Comment: Hey bro, Thanks really. I accidentally down-voted your answer and site doesn't let me to up vote it. anyway, I chose your answer cause It really simple and clever. Thanks really. You saved my day. Thanks @Paulie_D

Comment: You might be able to change your vote now I added a minor edit

Comment: Yeah i did that thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could set the width of both divs to be equal and then make them both flexboxes by applying these properties to both of them:

```css
    #dates {
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    #nums {
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    div div {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="dates">
        <div>Aug 5</div>
        <div>Aug 6</div>
        <div>Aug 7</div>
        <div>September 12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nums">
        <div>9</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what your looking for.

I both centered the tekst. So no matter what size the month is he always center it.

```css
#dates div{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20vw;
}
#nums div{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div>
    <div id="dates">
        <div class="showwidth">Aug 5</div>
        <div class="showwidth">Aug 6</div>
        <div class="showwidth">Aug 7</div>
        <div class="showwidth">September 12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nums">
        <div class="showwidth">9</div>
        <div class="showwidth">7</div>
        <div class="showwidth">5</div>
        <div class="showwidth">3</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works. But it's not the thing I need. I need that  nums be under the middle of dates.

Comment: Yeah my bad i read that wrong give me a sec.

Comment: It should be centered now as asked.